# Where is the Erchius mining facility?

Tags: starbound

I have the quest to go to the Erchius mining facility to check out a distress signal. I did the logical thing and went to the only moon in the current system (since that is the only area i can travel too), and there was nothing there. When I landed, I marked where I was and walked around the whole planet without finding any sort of structure.

Is it underground perhaps? I can mark the quest as current, will that give me any markers to indicate where to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got stuck for a little bit with this too. It isn't on an actual planet. You have to go to the sail computer thing and press current missions. It says erchius mining facility and when you click on it and then confirm you get teleported straight there from wherever you are.

Also heads up the boss has a blind spot above and beneath it to finish it. I say this coz I've died 10-20 times on this mission. Hope it goes well m8 :)

Comment: I also realized this last night and just came to answer, thanks for the tip.